# Does skiprows parameter in pandas.read_csv accepts a callable function?

Tags: python, pandas

I read the pandas documentation for the read_csv function and it says that it can accept a callable function for the skiprows parameter.

They have listed here (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) that a lambda expression can be used. However, when I tried to implement it I'm receiving this error:

*ValueError: Index Name invalid*

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv('student_scores.csv', index_col=['Name', 'ID'], skiprows= (lambda x: x in [0, 2]))
df.head()
```

Any guess as of why?

Thanks

PS. Print screen of data structure in csv.[image]

Comment: what's your `pandas.__version__`?

Comment: pandas version is 0.20.3

Comment: The link you give points to the docs of version `0.22`, but from what I could see skiprows should accept a callable also in version `0.20`. Could it be that instead the source of your problem is `index_col=['Name', 'ID']`? The error message seems to point to a problem with the `Name` column.

Comment: You are correct GPhilo. When I remove the multi-index I'm able to retrieve the dataset as I wanted to.

Comment: Please put the actual contents of the file (raw text) in the question. No one is able to read data from a screenshot with read_csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is going on is a combination of the effect of `skiprows = lambda x : x in [0, 2]` and `index_col=['Name', 'ID']`.

The first line in your file contains the column names, but `skiprows = lambda x : x in [0, 2]` makes you skip the first line (**which has index 0**). This way, `read_csv` doesn't infer the column names correctly and when you specify `index_col=['Name', 'ID']` it fails because it doesn't find any column with that name.

**Note:** I'm using @jezrael's example file as csv:

```
temp=u"""Name;ID;val
X;A;100
Y;A;50.5
Z;A;60
E;B;90
F;B;45
G;C;100"""
```

This:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=[0, 1], skiprows= [0, 2])
```

works because you specify the columns via their position, avoiding the names problem.

#### Proof:

```
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";", index_col=[0, 1], skiprows= lambda x : x in [1, 2]) # works, not skipping column names' row

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=";", names=['Name', 'ID', 'val'], index_col=[0, 1], skiprows= ['Name', 'ID']) # works (explicit column naming)
```

Comment: Yes, now understand.